# Github Actions Matrix include entries conditionally based on GitHub Events

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I currently have a workflow that triggers a deployment when merging to master and makes sure the dev job passes before deploying prod. There are a total of 4 environments (2 dev and 2 prod), I want to be able to reduce code duplication and reduce the number of jobs to 1 using github matrix if that's possible because the only thing that changes between jobs is the value of environmental variables.

The problem I'm running into is there doesn't seem to be a way to conditionally include or exclude entries based on a github event. If anybody has input or a knows of a good workaround I'd really appreciate it.

Files and contents are below.

apply.yaml:

```yaml
name: Terraform Apply

on:
  deployment:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: "name of the environment"
        required: true
        default: "dev"

env:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.KEY_ID_EXAMPLE }}
  AWS_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.KEY_EXAMPLE }}

jobs:
  deploy-dev:
    name: TF Apply - Dev
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.deployment.environment == 'dev' || github.event.deployment.environment == 'all' || github.event.inputs.environment == 'dev' || github.event.inputs.environment == 'all' }}
    env:
      TF_VAR_aws_provider_role_arn: arn:example
      TF_VAR_example_api_key: ${{ secrets.EXAMPLE_API_KEY }}
      TF_VAR_example_app_key: ${{ secrets.EXAMPLE_APP_KEY }}
      TF_WORKSPACE: dev
    steps:
    - name: Run Terraform Apply Composite
      uses: GetTerminus/example/multi-workspace/terraform-apply@1.0
      with:
        ssh_key: ${{ secrets.EXAMPLE_SSH_KEY }}

  deploy-dev-midwest:
    name: TF Apply - Dev Midwest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.deployment.environment == 'dev-midwest' || github.event.deployment.environment == 'all' || github.event.inputs.environment == 'dev-midwest' || github.event.inputs.environment == 'all' }}
    env:
      TF_VAR_aws_provider_role_arn: arn:example
      TF_VAR_example_api_key: ${{ secrets.DEV_MIDWEST_API_KEY }}
      TF_VAR_example_app_key: ${{ secrets.DEV_MIDWEST_APP_KEY }}
      TF_WORKSPACE: dev-midwest
    steps:
    - name: Run Terraform Apply Composite
      uses: GetTerminus/example/multi-workspace/terraform-apply@1.0
      with:
        ssh_key: ${{ secrets.GH_ACTIONS_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

  deploy-prod-east:
    name: TF Apply - Prod East
    needs: deploy-dev
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.deployment.environment == 'prod-east' || github.event.deployment.environment == 'all' || github.event.inputs.environment == 'prod-east' || github.event.inputs.environment == 'all' }}
    env:
      TF_VAR_aws_provider_role_arn: arn:example
      TF_VAR_example_api_key: ${{ secrets.PROD_EAST_API_KEY }}
      TF_VAR_example_app_key: ${{ secrets.PROD_EAST_APP_KEY }}
      TF_WORKSPACE: prod-east
    steps:
    - name: Run Terraform Apply Composite
      uses: GetTerminus/example/multi-workspace/terraform-apply@1.0
      with:
        ssh_key: ${{ secrets.GH_ACTIONS_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

  deploy-prod-midwest:
    name: TF Apply - Prod Midwest
    needs: deploy-dev-midwest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.deployment.environment == 'prod-midwest' || github.event.deployment.environment == 'all' || github.event.inputs.environment == 'prod-midwest' || github.event.inputs.environment == 'all' }}
    env:
      TF_VAR_aws_provider_role_arn: arn:example
      TF_VAR_example_api_key: ${{ secrets.PROD_MIDWEST_API_KEY }}
      TF_VAR_example_app_key: ${{ secrets.PROD_MIDWEST_APP_KEY }}
      TF_WORKSPACE: prod-midwest
    steps:
    - name: Run Terraform Apply Composite
      uses: GetTerminus/example/multi-workspace/terraform-apply@1.0
      with:
        ssh_key: ${{ secrets.GH_ACTIONS_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
```

deploy.yaml:

```yaml
name: Master Deployments

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  deploy-all:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Create Sequential Deployments
    uses: chrnorm/deployment-action@releases/v1
    with:
      token: ${{ secrets.GH_DEPLOYMENT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXAMPLE }}
      environment: all
```

Answer (score 2):

The matrix solution looks like this for your example:

```
name: Terraform Apply
on:
  push:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: "name of the environment"
        required: true
        default: "dev"

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        environment: [dev, dev-midwest, prod-east, prod-midwest]
    steps:
      - name: Deploy
        if: ${{ github.event.inputs.environment == 'all' || (matrix.environment == github.event.inputs.environment) }}
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "Hello World !!! ${{ matrix.environment }}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to address the `needs` clause present in the original apply.yaml, where the dev job is required to pass before the prod job can start.

Comment: Yeah the big thing blocking me is the needs field. I want both dev jobs to deploy successfully before the prod environments can deploy

Comment: I could break it up into two matrix jobs (1 for dev, other for prod) but that is suboptimal

Comment: Oh ok I see - matrix is only for parallel execution of the jobs so you won't be able to use that in that case. Sorry for missing this requirement I missed it.